# ComboBox is not fully Visible when I set Width less than 70px in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

ComboBox is not fully Visible when I set Width less than 70px?
What I have Tried is?

```
ComboBox ComboBox=new ConboBox();
ComboBox.width=50;
ComboBox.height=27;
```

I want ComboBox Width must be 50px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the default style of ComboBox, there is a **Border** named **Background** occupies two columns and its MinWidth is set as ComboBoxThemeMinWidth which is equals to 64px, so the MinWidth of ComboBox will be 64px. If you want to set its width as 50, you can set the MinWidth of Border as 50 or remove the MinWidth property and then apply new style. For example:

.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="ComboBox">
    ......
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                    ......
                    <Border x:Name="Background" MinWidth="50" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    ...... 
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

.cs:

```
ComboBox ComboBox = new ComboBox();
ComboBox.Width = 50;
ComboBox.Height = 27;
ComboBox.Style = (Style)this.Resources["ComboBoxStyle1"];
```

About the complete ComboBoxStyle1, you can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/wcj233/ComboBox_WidthApp/blob/master/ComboBoxApp/MainPage.xaml).

Comment: Do you mean when you click the arrow of ComboBox, the drop-down list can't display? I added some ComboBoxItems and the drop-down list displyed well.

Comment: its working now...i want dropdown list below the combobox...but it shows over the combobox...can you help me??

Comment: The DropDown actually is a Popup control in ComboBox's Template. We can not control it, it can only in upward direction. In that case, you can create a UserControl to design a custom control which behavior like a ComboBox and use Flyout to set its Placement as Bottom.